# Create a global javascript or jQuery variable visible in many pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a js variable with many functions, and I want to create in one of them a global variable visible in another php file that load the js file.

How can I do that ?

Thanks for help.

Thaks for help : here's an edit :

The variable has a dynamic value and is generated `on event.keyCode` I have tried in my js file: 
`window.selected_sku = null;` in the top of the js file

and in the appropriate function :

```
window.selected_sku =  v;
```

In my php within javascript code, I have :

```
    if(window.selected_sku!=null){
        alert(window.selected_sku);
    }
```

but I don't get any alert !!

Help..

Comment: If another php file loads the js file with this global variable, the global variable is already defined there. Just use it. =) Or give me more information about your problem.

Comment: @SomethVictory if it's a global variable, can't you just reference it by `yourVar`?

Comment: If you define a global var in a function, that function must be called before you can access the global var... obviously :)

Comment: @Rodolfo yes sure! you can use both way... I just prefer window.yourVar

Comment: Does this variable have a static or dynamic value?

Comment: Please see the edit on my original post, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assign it to window

```
window.variable = "this is a variable".
```

when you include the js file you can access the variable in any file.